# Ubuntu upstart use one script to run multiple others

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

This script will start the services:

```
#!upstart

description "example.com"
author      "Geert"

script
  for service in "website" "feeds" "jobs"
  do
    exec start service.example.com service=$service
  done
end script
```

The service script looks like this:

```
#!upstart

description "service.example.com"
author      "Geert"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0) 
stop  on shutdown

respawn                # restart when job dies

instance $service

script
  exec /home/fs/.nvm/v0.6.7/bin/coffee /home/fs/Dropbox/work/2012/krafters/$service.coffee
end script
```

The problem I have is that it only seems to be creating the website service.

```
initctl list | grep example
example.com stop/waiting
service.example.com (website) start/running, process 22787
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Upstart job configuration files (.conf files) are not scripts in the conventional sense: the first line you have ('`#!upstart`') is completely redundant and will be treated only as a comment.

Your problem is the use of '`exec`' in the first .conf file with the for loop: exec replaces the currently running shell with whatever argument you give exec so only the first entry in the for loop will be run.

To fix this, simply remove '`exec`' in the first .conf file.